# iOS IAP multiple original transaction ids refer to one same purchase with different original transaction id

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Originally, the original transaction id of the non-consumable purchase of iOS is one fixed id. And we can query it through iOS server API [Get Transaction History](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_transaction_history)

```
GET https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/history/{originalTransactionId}
```

However, we query different original transaction ids with the above API, and got one same transaction.

| Original Transaction id | get transaction history result |
| --- | --- |
| 10000960176789 | {"appAppleId":123567,"bundleId":"test.bundle.id","environment":"Production","hasMore":false,"revision":"1618209907000_210000866166345","trans":[{"transactionId":"10000866169876","originalTransactionId":"10000866169876","bundleId":"test.bundle.id","productId":"test.bundle.id.product1","purchaseDate":1618209883000,"originalPurchaseDate":1618209883000,"quantity":1,"type":"Non-Consumable","inAppOwnershipType":"PURCHASED","signedDate":1642422718461}]} |
| 10000960846532 | {"appAppleId":123567,"bundleId":"test.bundle.id","environment":"Production","hasMore":false,"revision":"1618209907000_10000866169876","trans":[{"transactionId":"10000866169876","originalTransactionId":"10000866169876","bundleId":"test.bundle.id","productId":"test.bundle.id.product1","purchaseDate":1618209883000,"originalPurchaseDate":1618209883000,"quantity":1,"type":"Non-Consumable","inAppOwnershipType":"PURCHASED","signedDate":1642422904634}]} |

And the original transaction id of the result of `get transaction history` is different from the original transaction id in the query. It is weriod.

Does anyone meet the same issue before? or is there anything am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was misunderstood the response of [History API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_transaction_history)

> Get Transaction History returns results for the following product types:
>
> - Auto-renewable subscriptions
> - Non-renewing subscriptions
> - Non-consumable in-app purchases
> - Consumable in-app purchases if the transaction is refunded, revoked, or if the app hasn't finished processing the transaction

Actually, the consumable purchase that has been finished does Not returned by this API.